# R Will Not Knit Histogram to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am currently trying to knit an R document. However, it refuses to knit a section of my markdown document that contains a bar graph. Just wondering if anyone here can give me a hand.

Here is the code:

```
hist(data_2$Q2, col="forestgreen", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), xlab="Likelihood of Voting", main="Frequency of Liklihood to Vote for Young Adults")

hist(data_3$Q2, col="blue", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,600), xlab="Likelihood of Voting", main="Frequency of Liklihood to Vote for Older Adults")

data_2 <- data[which(data$birthyr%in%1985:1996),]
data_3 <- data[which(data$birthyr%in%1924:1984),]
```

Here is what R has to say:

> Quitting from lines 59-68 (problemset2.Rmd)  Error in hist(data_2$Q2,
>   col = "forestgreen", xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0,  :    object
>   'data_2' not found Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers ->
>   withVisible -> eval -> eval -> hist In addition: Warning message: In
>   in_dir(input_dir(), evaluate(code, envir = env, new_device = FALSE,  :
>   You changed the working directory to
>   /Users/alexwang/Desktop/Government 10 R Folder/Government 10 (probably
>   via setwd()). It will be restored to /Users/alexwang/Downloads. See
>   the Note section in ?knitr::knit Execution halted

Hope someone could help.

Comment: object `data_2` is missing

Comment: To expand a little on what @PoGibas is saying -- when you knit a document, R runs the code in that document in a _fresh_ environment.  That means it cannot access things in your current global environment.  In other words, make sure you create `data_2` in the document that is being knit; it does you no good to have `data_2` sitting in your current global environment.

Comment: To expand on what @DanY is saying - you have the definition of `data_2` _after_ you use it in  the `hist` statement.  You must define it first.

Comment: To expand on what @G5W is saying  --  in Rstudio, try "Run- restart and run all chunks", you'll likely to spot the problem before knitr it.